# Currency Reverts Back When Change or Refresh Page on Shopify

Tags: javascript, cookies, shopify, currency

I have followed the guides below.

However the selected currency from the dropdown change when I change page.

It reverts back to the default currency.

Installed EditThisCookie and realized that the currency cookie does not update with the selector.

How do I fixed this?

Thanks!

https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/currencies/show-multiple-currencies

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/resolved-using-multiple-currency-switcher-with-the-supply-theme-prices-in-cart-wrong-when-currency-cookie-is-set-268399

Answer (score 0):

The currencies plugin does convert the price on page load, but then your theme updates that price again to the shop currency on product pages. You will need to locate the code in your theme that updates the price on product pages, and add conversion JavaScript in it.

Comment: While doing that, I would like to highlight:

The currency cookie does not update with the selector. Only the prices display update with the selector.

Using EditThisCookie, when I edited the cookie currency value, the price sticks even when I reload or change page.

Comment: For example edit cookie currency value to USD to EUR, it stays EUR throughout the session.

Somehow the selector cannot interact or create with the cookie. The codes from the guide can create the cookie but cannot edit it.

Just noticed that the cookie currency is only created when the product page is loaded

Comment: The selector name="currencies"

[currency-picker.liquid](https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/773649)
[currencies.liquid](https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/773624)